# How to pin a shared memory segment into physical memory

Tags: shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I use `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` to load a data structure in shared memory. I need to pin the shared memory segment into physical memory (for example similar to system call mlock for mapped files).

In linux, sooner or later my data structure gets swapped out of physical memory. In my case this incurs a forbidding cost for the next process accessing the structure, after it has been swapped out.

Is there any way to pin shared memory into physical memory? I am interested in any solution, even if it means that I cannot use `boost::interprocess`.

Comment: Temporarily I am using the swapoff command to disable the swap partition in order to accomplish this. This solution of course is not ideal...

Comment: Any luck with this? I am interested in this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `basic_managed_xsi_shared_memory` (apparently available since boost 1.46), you can access the underlying `shmid` (from the `get_shmid` member) which should allow you to control the shmid using `shmctl`. With shmctl you can prevent the swapping of shared memory pages by applying the `SHM_LOCK` command to the shmid.

Other types of locking (which you refer to as 'pinning'), such as locking memory mapped files into memory, can be realized by supplying return values obtained from `mapped_region`'s `get_address` and `get_size` member functions to the `mlock` command.